Children's book where a boy runs away from his foster home. Encounters a con man and travels with him
I read this when I was a child in the late 1980s to the early 1990s. It was probably a fairly short book, less than a hundred pages. It was set in the United States, probably in the mid 1800s to the early 1900s, at a time when riverboats were a primary form of transportation. The world was entirely mundane, despite any tall tales from the con man that might indicate otherwise.
I honestly don't recall if the boy's foster family was distant family, or strangers. I don't think they were technically abusive, at least not for the time, but they gave him the bare minimum of housing and food in exchange for constant chores, so he sets out to try to find his "real family". I remember he starts down the river early on, which is when he met the con man. Said con man hatched a scheme where they chopped down several cords of wood (I think with the boy reflecting on how he hadn't escaped the hard work from his foster situation) and then sold it to a passing riverboat captain for a combination of free passage and additional payment, with a tall tale regarding the land where they were (an island?) having formerly had a bunch of wild hogs who ran around, with their bodies, specifically the fat involved, having soaked into the wood, making it burn better. I have a vague memory that it was indicated that the captain recognized it as a story, but was willing to pay extra because it was a good story, and because then he could make the same claim to his passengers, that the ship was running on premium material.
After that, it's all a bit vague until a later scene where they run into someone with a "magic lantern" who was charging money for people to watch the show. This figured into a later scene where this was used to fake a ghost haunting, I believe projecting the image of the ghost onto a fog bank. Near the end of the book, the boy finds family, but they turn out to be greedy money-grubbers who try to snatch him up for indentured service like his foster family. The con man manages to free him, I think with the combination of the magic lantern and a chest which he'd had a blacksmith add a bunch of locks (and a band of iron wrapped around it) which he basically used to fool the family into thinking that there was a treasure, luring them away so that he could free the boy.
Ultimately, I want to say that the con man turned out to be the boy's father, or uncle, although I might be confusing that with them becoming family in a less blood sense.
I don't remember the cover of the book. There were some "pen and ink" drawings inside the book, serviceable but kind of sketchy in design and proportions, including them cutting the wood and the locked chest (there might have been one depicting the magic lantern show). I have a vague memory of the book being named "Name and the Grand Con Man" with the name being that of the boy. I don't remember the book every being part of school curriculum, so it's probably not a timeless classic, but more of an entertaining yarn. I would have read it where I grew up in Kentucky, on the off chance it's a regional thing.

Chancy and the Grand Rascal by Sid Fleischman perhaps.
From the Kirkus review:

The plot is an old saw —a teenage boy heads across country to find the
members of his family, which was split up when his parents died during
the Civil War. But here there's an extra, added, miracle ingredient—
Uncle Will Buckthorn. Chancy was chopping down trees for steamboat
fare and at the same time trying to look after his wheelbarrow-ful of
possessions and the brood of chicks which were hatching from the
"fresh" eggs he'd been buffaloed into buying when his Uncle Will first
appeared. It takes no time at all to discover that (for once) Will was
telling the straight truth when he claimed that "I can out-laugh,
out-exaggerate and out-rascal any man this side of the Big Muddy, and
twice as many on the other!" They work and they joke their way on to
steamboat passage, to reassembling the family, to traveling out to Sun
Dance, Kansas, and to capturing a band of outlaws.

It came up in worldcat.org search for su:Juvenile fiction  AND ti:"and the grand".

Ah, one of the covers looks very familiar. It looks like archive.org has a copy for lending. I will find out and let you know.

Excellent work! And looking at the author's other work, we read the McBroom's Farm stories all of the time as a child, and I remember The Whipping Boy existing, and I know the plot, although I don't think I ever read it.
